# xxd.lib file can not created from xx.vcproj file for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, cmake, cmake-gui

I generated built file with configuring openCV and openCV_contrib as sources on Cmake-gui programme.
When i start opencv.sln via visual studio 2013 64 bit , some core libraries of opencv cannot be created.(i.e.highgui310d.lib)

It informs "Build failed" at the bottom line and gives such like errors:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\opencv_highgui310d.lib'
>
> Build started: Project: opencv_highgui, Configuration: Debug x64
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ws2_32.lib'
>
> Build started: Project: opencv_test_highgui, Configuration: Debug x64
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\opencv_highgui310d.lib'

When i look directory "lib\Debug" , i can see some of libraries created but some of could not created that gave above error.

Also when i compile test_main.cpp og highgui module after did build solution,visial studio gives prompt like this:

> Unable to start program
>
> "..openCV/build/modules/highgui/x64/Debug/ALL_BUILD."
>
> Access denied.

I reinstalled many times and was careful about compatibility among created files respect to x64 and vs2013 64bit.

What can i do solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try compiling a second time? Sometimes CMake based projects (especially Qt based ones fail the first time).

Comment: Also when you configured in CMake-gui was there any dependency listed as `NOT-FOUND`?

Comment: Yes,i compiled many times and gives same error related to same libraries again and again.

Comment: If it is none of the problems I listed above. You will have to show the actual errors building the libraries not that error that says cannot open file.

Comment: Some c libraries pthread.h,fseek files showed as not found.Cmake creates highgui files that includes highgui.vcproj but i dont understand why it cannot achieve highguid.lib or highgui310d.lib

Comment: The ***Unable to start program

"..openCV/build/modules/highgui/x64/Debug/ALL_BUILD."*** is user error. You can't start a Visual Studio target that is not executable. ALL_BUILD is a target used to force generation of the other targets.

Comment: ***LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ws2_32.lib'*** I would google for this exact error. There should be a solution for that. Don't include CMake or opencv in your search terms it will be a more generic error.